# Are spontaneous exothermic reactions spontaneous due to more stable products or to an increase in the entropy of the surroundings?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, entropy

The lattice formation of an ionic compound from its infinitely separated gaseous ions is spontaneous under standard conditions, but I cannot figure out the 'driving force' behind this.

One way to look at this is that the charge particles try to minimize the electric potential energy of the system (as F=-dU/dx)

However, you can also look at this from the point of view of entropy. The large amount of heat given off increases the entropy of the surroundings more than the decrease in the entropy of the system, thereby increasing the total entropy of the universe.

Both of these point of views are clearly not linked as one is statistical while the other depends on the nature of the electric force.

So is the actual driving force the spontaneity of the electric force or statistical probability?

Comment: The energy could have been released in another and have the same effect on entropy.

Comment: Exothermic = you get products with lower enthalpy, which drives reaction. Entropy can hinder it or not - it's a tangential issue.

Comment: Gibbs free energy essentially gives an indication of the change in total entropy of the universe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is the actual driving force behind the spontaniety the electric force or statistical probability?

The driving force *has* to be the entropy, i.e., statistical probability.

The first law (conservation of energy) provides us no way to distinguish between the favorability of two different states of a system. It only tells us energy is neither created nor destroyed—it only changes form. It doesn't tell us if one form is more favored than another.

Thus, to determine whether a change will occur, i.e., to determine if one state is favored over another, we have to look at the second law (the entropy of the universe always increases for any macroscopic process).  This does distinguish between the favorability of the intial and final states.  It's the second law that provides an arrow of time for the universe.

So we can understand why oppositely-charged ions spontaenously combine at a given temperature as follows:  At that temperature, the gain in the entropy of the surroundings, due to the transformation of potential energy into thermal energy, is greater than the loss of the entropy of the system due to the ions combining.

At higher T, for the same heat flow, the gain in entropy of the surroundings will be less:

$$\Delta S = q_{rev}/T$$

Eventually we will reach a T at which, for this process, the entropy increase of the surroundings is less than the entropy loss of the system.  At that T, the ions will remain separated.*

*The test case being considered here is a phase change so, except at the phase coexistence temperature, it's either all one phase or all the other.  With a chemical reaction it's more complicated, since you can have an additional entropy term, the entropy of mixing, and thus the relative concentrations of the reactants and products will change as T changes, rather than going from all of one to all of the other.

Comment: Two charged particles spontaneously move towards each other because of the nature of the electric force; it's not even possible to apply the concept of entropy here as there are only 2 particles. Why can't we apply the same concept to a large number of ions? Why is it necessary to invoke entropy?

Comment: Good question!  Let's turn it around and ask:  Given we can't apply entropy to two individual oppositely charged particles, how do we explain why they will spontaenously combine?  They answer is: *they won;t*!  Here, as you said, entropy doesn't apply, so we only have conservation of energy.  As the particles move towards each other, their PE is converted to KE.   When they collide, all that KE will be converted back to PE (deformation of the electron cloud), which will then drive them apart.  I.e., they will repeatedly collide and bounce apart....

Comment: .....This is the time-reversal symmetry we see at the level of individual particles.   Only in the presence of other particles, to which they can transfer some of that exces energy, will they remain stuck together.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found the error in my understanding. I was under the impression that all chemical phenomenon were just governed by electrostatics and forgot that the decrease in potential energy always resulting in an increase in k.e that must be dissipated as heat

Comment: @theorist two colliding charged particles might radiate light.

Comment: @BuckThorn  You're right—charged particles should radiate EM when they are accelerating towards each other, suggesting they should continuously dissipate energy as they move apart and together.   I need to think about this some more.

Answer (score 0):

> Both of these point of views are clearly not linked as one is statistical while the other depends on the nature of the electric force.

They are linked by conservation of energy. If the reaction is exothermic (and there is no non-PV work), it will heat up the environment, and this helps to make the product state more likely than the reactant state. Another way of describing entropy increase is a dissipation of energy or matter. For an exothermic reaction, the energy once located in the reactants is now spread out over the environment (which might be a large water bath or something of that nature).

> Are spontaneous exothermic reactions spontaneous due to more stable products or to an increase in the entropy of the surroundings?

You are missing half of the necessary description. You have to consider not only how the entropy of the surrounding changes, but also how the entropy of the system (or the reacting species) changes. Otherwise, you would falsely assume that all exothermic reactions are spontaneous, which they are not.